# How to find element with dynamic id on row using webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have got html of element:

```
<li class="cabinet-module-holder cabinet-module-w4" ng-repeat="module in $ctrl.cabinetRow.modules track by module.id" dnd-draggable="module" dnd-effect-allowed="move" dnd-moved="$ctrl.removeModule($index, 1)" dnd-type="'0a2e00b3-8f89-4d17-a0c8-d37876043316'" dnd-dragstart="$ctrl.moduleDragStart({ cabinetModuleId: module.id })" dnd-disable-if="false" draggable="true">
```

I am using Webdriver framework in Visual Studio to move element on the rail/row. I want to valdiate that this element is on rail. When the element is bigger cabinet module is w6 when it is small element is w2. The w4 is a medium size of each element.

Now I have short C# code:

```
string searchText = "0a2e00b3-8f89-4d17-a0c8-d37876043316";
                IList<IWebElement> rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='cabinet-body']"));
                foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
                {
                    if (row.Text.Contains(searchText))
                    {
                        SelectElement select = new SelectElement(row.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='cabinet-module-holder cabinet-module-w6']")));
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

In the log output window I have empty place. For that I use function `logger.Write();`

I want to validate element - it should be on correct rail, but the id is dynamic and after new browser or refresh is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I have used many times when working with dynamic elements. It sounds like the id is more or less the same with the exception of `w2`, `w4` or `w6`. The following link taught me how to make advanced css selectors, which I have used to handle dynamic elements.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/

For your given element you could write this many ways

`li[class^='cabinet-module-holder cabinet-module']`

Answer (score 0):

use xpath

```
//*[contains(@class,'w4')]
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, it is always encouraged to add an explanation explaining why/how it works to it.